# Are there any wifi/bluetooth combo adapters that work with the Pi?

Tags: usb, wifi, bluetooth

I am looking for a usb adapter that will support both wifi and bluetooth on a single usb port, are there any that work for the Pi?

More specifically, are there any that support atleast Wifi N and Bluetooth 4.0+ (looking for BLE capabilities)?

related: [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=27678), but it's a bit old and im hoping to find one with bluetooth 4.0 or higher

Comment: You could research adapters individually in your order of preference, and search for "linux" and not "raspberry pi", since it's the driver software that's actually relevant.  I'd guess those things are really two devices in one, and a separate driver is used for each.  If you can find out the chipsets used, these are often referenced by name in the kernel source, which makes it easy to confirm it *should* work (and to search online for reports that it actually *doesn't* work, since people generally do not post about how something *does* work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an updated list here http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Bluetooth_adapters#Working_Bluetooth.2FWifi_Combo_adapters

But your mileage may vary, make sure you are using a quality power supply/USB hub.

Please comment when you do get one that works.

Comment: I don't see any 4.0+ BT adapters on that list (of combo adapters), so I think I will just be going the "typical" way of separate dongles + a hub for now

Answer (score 4):

The RPi3 has combined wifi and Bluetooth 4.1.

This is using the same BCM43143 which was used by broadcom in their wifi+usb hub

[image]

https://www.broadcom.com/application/internet_of_things.php

> ## ALL ABOUT WICED™
>
> ### Meet WICED, Wireless Internet Connectivity for Embedded Devices.
>
> Interoperability is critical to the proliferation of
>   the Internet of Things, which is why the WICED™ (pronounced “wik-id”)
>   platform is bringing secure Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and Bluetooth Low Energy
>   (BLE) wireless connectivity to nearly every emerging product category
>   in the Internet of Things ecosystem, including home appliances, health
>   and fitness monitors, automation and asset tracking systems, smart
>   meters and an array of consumer electronics devices.  The WICED™
>   portfolio of development systems enables Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and BLE
>   connectivity for:
>
> - Home appliances
> - Home monitoring and control Health and fitness
> - Automation and logistics
> - Digital cameras and imaging
> - Smart meters and
>     energy management
> - "Headless" devices without a means of interactive
>     configuration for connectivity
> - PAN-LAN bridge and cloud applications
> - Consumer Electronics

So this device is capable of Bluetooth, but perhaps the software never supported it. I haven't seen anyone using it for Bluetooth apart from the WICED dongle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This combo adapter (BW-1518) is plug and play on Pi (no drivers to compile).  Both wifi and bluetooth can run for days without crashing the Pi.

I've seen memory leaks with newer devices like the rtl8273xxx, that crash the Pi in about an hour.   But the BW-1518 is getting hard to find -- but not impossible.  I had no luck finding the other devices listed in the post.